Can you delombok all classes at once?
There's a nice "delombok" feature, at least in IntelliJ. So, for example, you can replace @Getter with explicit getters in a couple of clicks in any given class
Can you delombok all your classes in one go? Googling didn't help

https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok

Did you tried https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok?
Documentation says you need to:
java -jar lombok.jar delombok src -d src-delomboked

